# Puppeteer.js - scraping list of domains and storing data

Tags: javascript, arrays, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have some problems with scraping list of urls and storing data from them at array. I think my main problem is the puppeter and browser context.

I want to check anchor texts, but only at anchors with specific string on href attribute.

**Steps:**

1. Initialize chromium setting
2. Use for loop on array with urls
3. At for loop, select all occurrences of such urls and **scrape** anchor texts
4. **And now I have problem** with storing it at some variable with scope beyond for loop and in puppeteer context

I used a few methods `page.evaluate()`, `page.evaluateHandle()`, `page.$$()`, `page.$$eval()`, but my issues are:

1. Going to new page seems to overwritten previous value, because of Chromium reloading
2. I don't have a proper idea how to use spread operator / push to cloned array at puppetter.js context.

The ideal way I think is passing data every time from browser context variables to puppeter.js context variable.

Would be glad for any tips / solutions :) Code below

Index.js file:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const jsonFile = require("./example.json");
const numberOfUrls = jsonFile.urls.length;
const urlsArray = jsonFile.urls;

(async () => {
  try {
    // initial settings for Chromium
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      defaultViewport: null,
      headless: false,
      devtools: true,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setUserAgent(
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
    );

    await page.setViewport({ width: 0, height: 0, deviceScaleFactor: 1 });

    // for loop on urls list
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfUrls; i++) {
      await page.goto(urlsArray[i]);
      await page.waitFor(1000);
      const elements = await page.$$eval( `a[href*="https://mysuperdomain.com/"]`,  elements => elements.map(el => el.innerText));
      console.log(await {url: urlsArray[i],
         urlsTexts: elements});

    }
    //end for loop
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Catched error: ${error}`);
  }

})();
```

example.json file:

```
{
    "urls": [
        "https://exampledomain1.com/something/",
        "https://exampledomain2.com/something/",
        "https://exampledomain3.com/something/"
    ]
}
```

Preferred output:

```
[{
  url: 'https://exampledomain1.com/something/',
  urlsTexts: [ 'learn more', 'go to our partner' ]
},
{
  url: 'https://exampledomain2.com/something/',
  urlsTexts: [ 'go to mysuperdomain', 'check on mysuperdomain.com' ]
}]
```

Comment: From a quick glance your code looks almost fine. Just replace the `console.log()` with something like `results.push()` and drop the `await` there.

Comment: Thanks for info :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a few corrections:

```js
// for loop on urls list

const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < numberOfUrls; i++) {
  await page.goto(urlsArray[i]);
  await page.waitFor(1000);
  const elements = await page.$$eval( `a[href*="https://mysuperdomain.com/"]`,  elements => elements.map(el => el.innerText));
  result.push({ url: urlsArray[i], urlsTexts: elements });
}

console.log(result);

//end for loop
```

Comment: Thx, this works fine for me, I got what I wanted ;)